# Turning a 1-D numpy array into a N-d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm not sure if this is called broadcasting or something else, but supposed I'm given a 1-D numpy array of size `L`. I want to turn this into an n-dimensional numpy array, where one of the dimensions is of size `L` and the other dimensions are arbitrary, but greater than 0.

e.g., suppose L = 2 and I want to turn this into a `n=2`-dimensional array of size `2x3` (2 rows, 3 columns), in this case, each row will consist of the original 1-D array.

Is there a function that will allow me to do this in numpy?

Comment: First reshape it to (2,1).  Expanding to (2,3) will be then be easier (and easier to visualize).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use [`broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy.broadcast_to). You could also use the [`tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) function to a similar effect.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)
print('Array before:')
print(a)
print('Array after:')
np.broadcast_to(a,(3,10))
```

Result:

```
Array before:
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
Array after:

array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Ah I think this is it, but why can't I do `np.broadcast_to(a,(10,3))`? This gives the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (10,)  and requested shape (10,3)`

Comment: By the  rules of broadcasting, new leading dimensions are automatic, but trailing dimensions have to be explicit.  `np.broadcast_to(a[:,None],(10,3))`. expands a (10,1) to (10,3).  Ben's example expands a (10,) to (1,10) to (3,10).